# What does "the same" refer to in this quote from the Reactive Manifesto?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is the first few lines of the [Reactive Manifesto](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/):

> Organisations working in disparate domains are independently
>   discovering patterns for building software that look the same. These
>   systems are more robust, more resilient, more flexible and better
>   positioned to meet modern demands.

In the first sentence what does "look the same" refer to? "Patterns" or "software"?

Comment: Patterns.  That is, patterns for building software.  Software would not take a plural verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Software" is singular, and the verb "look" is plural, so we'll have to go back farther to find a suitable antecedent.  The first we encounter is the plural "patterns."  The "Reactive Manifesto" describes similar sets of requirements that give rise to similar software architectures.  It's plausible that these might be "patterns for building software." Although the "Manifesto" gives no operational definition of how patterns are employed to build software, I think we've found the antecedent:  "patterns."

Comment: I agree, but a friend of mine argues that software is non-countable, thus have no plural form, how should I convince him?

Comment: Your friend is right:  there is no plural form for "software," which is one way to understand why it's singular.  Most non-countable nouns like "software" are.

Comment: he basically thinks singular and plural form of "software"  are the same! and in above context, he thinks "software" is used as a plural name!!

Comment: Your friend may be confusing the fact that the collective noun "software" may include many different programs but that grammatically it is still treated as singular in number.

Comment: What a great example of a seemingly trivial grammar issue that would change the meaning of the sentence if it were wrong.